# Python - Convert negative decimals from string to float

Tags: python, string, decimal

I need to read in a large number of .txt files, each of which contains a decimal (some are positive, some are negative), and append these into 2 arrays (genotypes and phenotypes). Subsequently, I wish to perform some mathematical operations on these arrays in scipy, however the negative ('-') symbol is causing problems.  Specifically, I cannot convert the arrays to float, because the '-' is being read as a string, causing the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Here is my code as it's currently written:

```
import linecache

gene_array=[]
phen_array=[]

for i in genotype:

   for j in phenotype:

      genotype='/path/g.txt'
      phenotype='/path/p.txt'

      g=linecache.getline(genotype,1)
      p=linecache.getline(phenotype,1)

      p=p.strip()
      g=g.strip()

      gene_array.append(g)
      phen_array.append(p)

  gene_array=map(float,gene_array)
  phen_array=map(float,phen_array)
```

I am fairly certain at this point that it is the negative sign that is causing the problem, but it is not clear to me why. Is my use of Linecache the problem here? Is there an alternative method that would be better?

The result of

```
print gene_array
```

is

```
['-0.0448022516321286', '-0.0236187263814157', '-0.150505384829925', '-0.00338459268479522', '0.0142429109897682', '0.0286253352284279', '-0.0462358095345649', '0.0286232317578776', '-0.00747425206137217', '0.0231790239373428', '-0.00266935581919541', '0.00825077426011094', '0.0272744527203547', '0.0394829854063242', '0.0233109171715023', '0.165841084392078', '0.00259693465334536', '-0.0342590874424289', '0.0124600520095644', '0.0713627590092807', '-0.0189374898081401', '-0.00112750710611284', '-0.0161387333242288', '0.0227226505624106', '0.0382173405035751', '0.0455518646388402', '-0.0453048799717046', '0.0168570746329513']
```

Comment: You'll have to show the actual data you are trying to read.  A string like `"-123.45"` can be `float`'ed just fine, but `"-  123.45"` cannot.

Comment: can you print `gene_array` and `phen_array`?  Perhaps your text files are empty and you're trying to `float` an empty string?

Comment: I doubt this is your actual code - in its current form it will throw an UnboundLocalError on `for i in genotype` as you define the variable inside of the loop; also you're never using `i` or `j` anywhere...

Comment: @J R: Could you also print `phen_array`?

Comment: You seem to be reading the same line over and over and over ... is that really what you want here?

Comment: I can `map(float,gene_array)` just fine...

Comment: I have the same problem and I believe that its due to -ve number .. not empty string .. I know that because I get the same error when the value has -ve sign in front of it .. when I remove it, I can convert just fine ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be with empty string or space as evident from your error message

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

To make it work, convert the map to a list comprehension

```
gene_array=[float(e) for e in gene_array if e]
phen_array=[float(e) for e in phen_array if e]
```

By empty string means

`float(" ")` or `float("")` would give value errors, so if any of the items within `gene_array` or `phen_array` has space, this will throw an error while converting to float

There could be many reasons for empty string like

- empty or blank line
- blank line either at the beginning or end

Comment: No need to do the `strip`, it was already done as the original list was generated.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Agreed I missed that part

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick.  And yes - I had to condense the code for readability.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the error message to suggest that `-` is the problem. The most likely reason is that `gene_array` and/or `phen_array` contain an empty string (`''`).

As stated in the documentation, `linecache.getline()`

> will return `''` on errors (the terminating newline character will be included for lines that are found).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the "empty string at the end of g and/or p"?  Every string has an empty string at the end -- And at the beginning and ... OP is only reading line 1 (over and over and over) which is fishy ...

Comment: the p=p.strip() (etc) should have taken care of the whitespace, no?

Comment: @mgilson: Bad wording on my part. I meant `gene_array` and `phen_array` where I said `g` and `p`.

Comment: @NPE -- Ahh, I'm following now.  Yes, an empty string there would be a problem -- But I don't know how that would get in there with the way OP is using linecache (unless that line didn't exist in the file).  Anyway, It appears the OP isn't being completely honest with us ... :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is definitely not in the negative sign. Python converts strings with negative sign without a problem. I suggest you run each of your entries against a float RegEx and see if they all pass.