# Python - ValueError: invalid literal for float()

Tags: python, csv, numpy, string-parsing

I have a csv file that I'm trying to convert its data into Dense Design Matrix using *Pylearn2* module. However what causes error is not related to pylearn2 but to my personal implementation.

```
import csv
def load_data(fileName_X, start, stop):
    with open(fileName_X, 'r') as f:
        reader_X = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
        X = []
        header = True
        size=0
        for row_X in reader_X:
            if header:
                header = False
                continue
            row_X = [float(elem_X) for elem_X in row_X]
            size+=1
            X.append(row_X)
        X = np.asarray(X)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    train = load_data(sys.argv[1], 0, 10)
```

Here is some rows of the .csv file:

```
-1;-0.844511;-0.339286;-1;0.0769231;-0.25;-0.929825;1;1;-0.880597;1;0;-0.92;-0.99
1;-0.796992;-0.8275;-1;0.0769231;-0.25;-0.859649;1;1;-0.671642;1;-1;-0.8;-0.94
1;-0.611429;-0.875;-1;0.0769231;-0.25;-0.929825;1;1;-0.850746;1;-1;-0.84;-0.88446
-1;-0.661654;-0.119286;-1;0.846154;0.75;-0.754386;1;1;-0.820896;-1;-1;-0.6;-0.99084
```

Normally what I expect is to have all the values of each row which are separated by `;` in `row_X`. But as I run the program, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_dataset.py", line 68, in <module>
    train = load_data(sys.argv[1], 0, 10)
  File "make_dataset.py", line 53, in load_data
    row_X = [float(elem_X) for elem_X in row_X]
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1;-0.796992;-0.8275;-1;0.0769231;-0.25;-0.859649;1;1;-0.671642;1;-1;-0.8;-0.94
```

What I can't find out the reason is that the program works properly with another csv file which contains these rows (just to compare its possible different form with the first one):

```
7.4;0.7;0;1.9;0.076;11;34;0.9978;3.51;0.56;9.4;5
7.8;0.88;0;2.6;0.098;25;67;0.9968;3.2;0.68;9.8;5
7.8;0.76;0.04;2.3;0.092;15;54;0.997;3.26;0.65;9.8;5
11.2;0.28;0.56;1.9;0.075;17;60;0.998;3.16;0.58;9.8;6
```

Comment: Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145460/python-convert-negative-decimals-from-string-to-float

Comment: A quick aside:  To skip a header row just do `next(reader_X)` before your for-loop.

Comment: This doesn't directly address your bug, but you [might want use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315506/load-csv-into-2d-matrix-with-numpy-for-plotting) [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt)

Comment: @FirebladeDan I've just tried to discover if the problem is caused by the negative sign in some rows with iPython. Unfortunately this is not the case. _float()_ works properly with negative signs even. As for spaces, I'm sure there is no space in none of the rows.

Comment: It's trying to parse the entire line into a single number. You need to split it up and parse each element in the line.

Comment: Perfect idea @StevenRumbalski. I'll try that if this could not be solved by tonight ;)

Comment: From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html): *If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.* Don't know if that's the problem, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3:  You are correct, but he's using `csv.reader` which should be splitting the line correctly.

Comment: @MarkRansom:  It's important to note that the binary flag is needed in Python 2 only.  So if OP is using Python 2, he should try this.  In Python 3 the docs change to "If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''`."

Comment: This is a critical point. What platform/version of Python are you running?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski it's not just Python 2, but Python 2 on Windows - Linux qualifies as a platform where 'b' doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @NathanBartley Python 2.7.10 (if the OS is important, it's Linux Debian). I'm just tying to check all the responses if they may solve the problem. Thanks for all.

Comment: That's very strange because I ran your code & bad input verbatim on OSX/2.7.2 and could not replicate your problem.

Comment: This code (with the example data) works with both Python 2 and Python 3 for me. Since you seem to not get the error on the first row but only with the second, can you add a `print(repr(row_X))` before the float line to see what Python sees?

Comment: @poke:  I believe the reason he sees the error on row 2 is that he is skipping a non-existent header row.

Comment: I've tried adding a header to the csv file (the first one which produces the error). It seems that the problem is caused by the second row, whatever it be: `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): -1;-0.844511;-0.339286;-1;0.0769231;-0.25;-0.929825;1;1;-0.880597;1;0;-0.92;-0.99`.What is still shady to me is that the second csv file doesn't produce any error as I run the program (You may take a deeper look into the second dataset here: [Wine Quality Data Set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality) Click on _Data Folder_ link plz)

Comment: Instead of using `csv`, have you tried using `numpy.fromtxt(f, delimiter=';')` after skipping the header?

Comment: @codewarrior I could temporarily resolve the problem using `reader_X = np.genfromtxt(fileName_X, delimiter=';')`. But the problem using csv rests always.